# How to remove the scaling and offset attributes of a variable in a netcdf file to get the actual data values

Tags: netcdf, atmosphere, nco, cdo-climate

I have a variable which has the dimensions time x lat x lon x levels and I am trying to read this in my global climate model. The problem I am facing is that the data is scaled and offset in the original file and it is a hassle to incorporate this inside the model. I want to modify the file so that the original data without any scaling or offset is available to read in the climate model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following syntax to unpack the scale and offset in the data

```
ncpdq --unpack input_file.nc out_file.nc
```

The file out_file.nc will contain the actual values without any scaling or offset

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
cdo -b 32 copy input_file.nc out_file.nc
```

or this

```
cdo -b f32 copy input_file.nc out_file.nc
```

essentially it unpacked the data by converting it to a 32 bit float.  If you want a 64 bit double precision float you can use 64 instead 32.